# How to get the next floating point value (upwards or downwards)?

Tags: java, floating-point

Suppose we have a situation like this: we have an upper bound (which is a `float`), as well as a flag "strict" (`boolean`). We want to scan through a list of values (floats) and do something to each value which satisfies the bound.

The check would look something like this:

```
value -> strict ? (value < bound) : (value <= bound)
```

It's not the end of the world, but `bound` and `strict` are defined far away from this check, and for code locality reasons it would be nice not to send `strict` all the way through the process.

It would be convenient, if it's possible, to just move bound "up to the next value" so that instead of checking `value <= bound` we could just check `value < boundPlusALittleBit`.

If we use `ints` instead of `floats`, this is easy (`boundPlusALittleBit = bound + 1`) but it's not straightforward to do this with floats. Is there a library function which achieves this?

Comment: can you provide a small example here of what exactly you mean?

Comment: @Eugene it's difficult to provide an explicit example, except by analogy, but rgettman's answer seems to be exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [`Math.nextUp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp(double)) and [`Math.nextDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextDown(double)), both overloaded for both `float` and `double` parameters.

> Returns the floating-point value adjacent to `d` in the direction of positive infinity.
>
> Returns the floating-point value adjacent to `d` in the direction of negative infinity.

Comment: I just tried it out, I don't about the exact precision, but they are not incrementing by a unit. Here are the results I printed in a loop (this may be due to println's way of printing the floats)

0.10000001  
0.10000002  
0.100000024  
0.10000003  
0.10000004  
0.100000046  
0.10000005  
0.10000006  
0.10000007  
0.100000076  
0.10000008  
0.10000009  
0.1000001  
0.100000106

Comment: The conversion to `String` for display is rounding.  It's really adding `Math.ulp(value)`, which is the smallest increment that can be added (or subtracted) to `value`.  With `0.1f`, `Math.ulp` is `7.4505806E-9`.

Comment: @MadhusoodanP You can use `BigDecimal` to print the "real" value of a float. e.g. https://ideone.com/UFqFEJ

Comment: @zapl Thank you :). But the idea of printing was just to see are we updating in noticable way.